# Spring Quartz and CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, quartz-scheduler

I currently have a Spring Boot Application using CrudRepository happily

I needed some of it to run in batch so ive created a second application with Spring Boot and Quartz

all was well until I tried the following

ive got a standard Job which is part of a scheduler which has some services wired in like so

```
public class LeaguesJob {




@Autowired
FootyPicksService footyPicksService;

@Autowired
FootyPicksEmailService footyPicksEmailService;

@Autowired
private FixturesService fixturesService;

@Autowired
private RegistrationService regService;

@Autowired
PaymentsService paymentsService;
```

However when the application is starting up if one of those services wires a Dao interface extending CrudRepository like this

```
public class PaymentsServiceImpl implements PaymentsService {

@Autowired
PaymentDao paymentDao;
```

and heres the Dao

```
public interface PaymentDao extends CrudRepository<Payment, Integer > {

List<Payment> findPaymentsByLeagueIdAndRoundNumber (int leagueId , int roundNumber);
```

}

Then i just get these exceptions as if the CrudRpository bean isnt available

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'paymentsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'paymentDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.footy.picks.dao.PaymentDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

i've looked around at read many examples about how these objects are not instantiated by Spring but by Quartz, and have tried some of the workarounds

however the symptoms seem to be null objects after start up whereas here the application wont start

any ideas would be welcome...

EDIT - XML batch job

```
    <!--   leagues processor   -->


<bean name="leaguesJob" class="com.footy.picks.leagues.processing.LeaguesJob" />

<bean name="leaguesSchedulerBean" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">

<property name="jobFactory" >  
   <bean class="com.footy.picks.batch.AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory"/>  
 </property>  

    <property name="jobClass" value="com.footy.picks.leagues.processing.LeaguesJobScheduler" />

    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
      <map>
        <entry key="leaguesJob" value-ref="leaguesJob" />
      </map>
    </property>

    <property name="durability" value="true" />

</bean>

<bean id="leaguesTrigger"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">

    <property name="jobDetail" ref="leaguesSchedulerBean" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="180000" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="1" />

</bean>


<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="fixturesSchedulerBean" />
            <ref bean="picksSchedulerBean" />
            <ref bean="leaguesSchedulerBean" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
            <ref bean="picksTrigger" />
            <ref bean="leaguesTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and heres the payment service

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="paymentsService" class="com.footy.picks.payments.service.PaymentsServiceImpl" >

</bean>
```

Comment: How have you defined the spring beans that you are autowiring? I see no annotation on the classes so I suppose you used anXML definition

Comment: yes have the services in a xml file

Comment: Could you attach the XML configuration? It will be helpful

Comment: added above as asked

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by araknoid, did you annotate your PaymentDao interface with the @Repository annotation?

Comment: hey  - no i haven't  - in my main application also I don't and it works fine - my understanding is Spring provides the implementation for CrudRepository and will add to the application context as part of its component scan . However having said that i have just tried this to the same result

Answer (score 0):

As reported at the [Spring JPA doc (3.5. Creating repository instances)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances), you have to enable Spring Data repositories via XML:

```
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

  <repositories base-package="com.footy.picks.payments" />

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: I don’t think so - the implementation is in the spring data JPA jars . I don’t implement it - that’s how it’s working in my other applications - all you do is extend the interface

Comment: @philthomas26 I looked more in details to your code and updated my answer properly. Sorry for the mistake made earlier.